# Multiplying two very big numbers results in showing '-1' or '0'

Tags: java, double

When i multiply two big numbers (in Double) , for example 2^64 the answer i get from my programm is '-1' and when i calculate 2^32 the answer i get from my programm is '0'. but when i tried multiplying smaller numbers, such us 2^10 i get the right answer.
why is it happening?
for example the code:

```html
System.out.println(2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2)
```

prints out '0' insted of  '18446744073709552000'

Comment: Show the code that is not working. `System.out.println(Math.pow(2,64) * Math.pow(2,64)):` prints `3.4028236692093846E38` as expected... So the problem is not the multiplication but how you use the result.

Comment: for example the code:  System.out.println(2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2) prints '0' insted of  '18446744073709552000'

Comment: You overflowed the `int` range; it will overflow the `long` range too.

Comment: If you want to calculate large numbers without worrying about overflow then use BigInteger or BigDecimal. Also be aware if you want a result to be a long then at least one of the numbers you're multiplying must be a long. So 2 * 2 evaluates to an int value but 2 * 2L will evaluate to a long.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question related to range of the primitive datatypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53354958/question-related-to-range-of-the-primitive-datatypes)

Comment: What should be in BigDecimal? the variable that stores the result? one of the numbers i calculate? two of them?